# How to prevent form submission from firing continuously?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a text field where the user enters a message, clicks enter and it submits it into the database. The problem is, it always submits multiple times depend on how many milliseconds the enter key is pressed. I'm not actually doing any field validation, it's more of a proof of concept while learning. Also I know I can disable the submit form entirely after a single submission but I want to be able to continue entering messages.

```
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter message" id="enterMsg">
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#enterMsg").submit(function(){
    var uid = $("#enterMsg").val();
    Messages.insert({text: uid});


  })
```

Should I be using a different html tags or jquery functions?

Comment: I think you could trigger form submit manually after you finish what you are doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you admit that this is purely acedemic, because no one in their right mind would deploy something this insecure...

You could have a global variable that will determine if a submission should be accepted or rejected.  Before a submission is accepted check the global variable. If it is set to TRUE, accept the submission and immediately set the global variable to FALSE.  Create a timeout of, say, 1 second to reset the global variable to TRUE.

This will only allow one submission per second from a given user.

```
<form id="myform">
<input type="text" placeholder="Enter message" id="enterMsg">
<input type="submit" />
</form>
var accept_flag = true;
time_between_submissions = 1000;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#myform").submit(function(){
     if (accept_flag) {
         var uid = $("#enterMsg").val();
         Messages.insert({text: uid});
         accept_flag = false;
         setTimeout(function() { accept_flag = true; },time_between_submissions);
     }


});
```

Of course, none of this would matter because if you're doing a proper POST form submission, as soon as the form is submitted, the browser is not going to allow it to be resubmitted by holding down the ENTER key.

If you're doing this via AJAX, you wouldn't use the .submit() method, you would listen for a keyPress event on the form, and then yes, you'd need to implement a way to throttle the submissions.

Comment: Still new to stackoverflow, guess I can't upvote yet and only one answer can be flagged as correct. But thanks to both of you, definitely set me down the right path. Thank you both so much.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, i think you can't have .submit() on a textfield. I would do this with a form.

HTML:

```
<form id="myform">
   <input type="text" placeholder="Enter message" id="enterMsg" />
</form>
```

JS:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var submitted = false;
  $("#myform").submit(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    if(!submitted) {
       var uid = $("#enterMsg").val();
       Messages.insert({text: uid}); 
       submitted = true; /* You can clear the input or hide the form, or something */
    }

  });
});
```

[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/B6BQE/)